# Force to close current window first in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I'm working WPF application, Currently it has one window and at specific time *(As per my requirement)*. It's displayed on top most priority.

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
this.Topmost = true;
```

Now, I want like user should close first this windows(WPF application window), till cannot access any other thing from system.(user cannot able access even other application also) *Seems like to force close first this window*

I've been searched, but not getting anything.

How Can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Imagine another application tried to do the same thing at the same time - you can't close window A before window B, but you can't close window B before window A, but...

Edit: the short version above can be misunderstood, so in more detail:

Let's say, your application has this very important message for the user, so it opens a special window. The special property of this window is that as long as it exists, the user can't access any other window. This also means, the user cannot *close* any other window.
Now while the user reads the message, another application has an important message, so it opens a window, using the same method as you to block access to other windows until it is closed.

The user cannot close the second window, because the first window is special and must be closed first. The user cannot close the first window, because the second window is special and must be closed first => the UI is completely locked. The poor user must use Task Manager to kill one of the two applications or reboot the system.

See also [Raymond Chen's more detailed discussion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) of this principle.

Comment: *Imagine another application tried to do the same thing at the same time* **Make sense.** *you can't close window A before window B, but you can't close window B before window A, but.* **not getting you!**

Comment: The linked page gives a more detailed explanation - if that still doesn't help you, I shall try and rephrase my answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link, but i don't wont to close window A before window B, Suppose i have two application one is notepad and second is my application window, now at specific time my application window comes up on the top, Now I just want like user can not able access notepad till not close my current window, I hope it does make sense!

Comment: *The user cannot close the second window, because the first window is special and must be closed first. The user cannot close the first window, because the second window is special and must be closed first* **No** any other process should on second priority.

Comment: I've seen many times in *cyber cafe*. cafe has some custom login portal, were you front of system, system asked for credential, if you enter valid then and then you can access that system otherwise not able to do anything